# execute swap instruction using VersionedTransaction

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, send-transaction, sendtransactionerror, versionedtransactions

i am trying to execute swap instruction using VersionedTransaction and i'm getting this error.

```
const messageV0 = new TransactionMessage({
    payerKey: payer.publicKey,
    recentBlockhash: blockhash,
    instructions,
}).compileToV0Message();
const tx = VersionedTransaction(messageV0);
tx.sign([payer]);
const signature = await connection.sendTransaction(tx);
```

SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete

'Program failed to complete: exceeded maximum number of instructions allowed (200000) at instruction #51147'

Answer (score 2):

Try increasing the compute limit for the transaction.

Solana cookbook reference: https://solanacookbook.com/references/basic-transactions.html#how-to-change-compute-budget-fee-priority-for-a-transaction

> By default the compute budget is the product of 200,000 Compute Units
> (CU) * number of instructions, with a max of 1.4M CU.
>
> Use `ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({ units: number })` to set the
> new compute budget. The value provided will replace the default value.
> Transactions should request the minimum amount of CU required for
> execution to maximize throughput, or minimize fees.